# my program wont run from command prompt

Tags: python-2.7

I need help here I wrote code for my lab that "The loop will iterate a total of 10 times using the value of a variable that is incremented by one each time the loop completes."**strong text** but when I run my python file by click just open it refuse to run in command prompt...When I test in Edit with IDLE it runs fine...I can't figure out why it wont run...
   here is what I wrote for my code:

```
   counter = 0
   while counter < 10:
         counter = counter + 1
          print counter
    print "the loop is finished"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "refuse to run".  Does it produce an error message of some kind?  If so, could you edit your question to include a copy of the message?

Comment: it just blinks and don't run in cmd prompt...like others labs i did they run in cmd prompt when I click on my file but this one is not running...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's just done way too fast.

Have you tried adding a `raw_input()` at the bottom of the file?

Comment: In that case it worked before, but Windows simply closes the window when it's done processing. So you have to add something like `raw_input()` or `time.sleep(10)` to make sure you see the output. You can also execute from `cmd` instead so it won't close.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have indentation errors (mainly with the print statements being indented one space further than the code above them).

Does this work for you:

```
counter = 0
    while counter < 10:
        counter = counter + 1
        print counter
    print "the loop is finished"
```

Python has strict indentation rules, if you want to learn more about them I would suggest reading [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics), it's pretty good.